# sql max of count 2 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

i've been searching for literally hours (1pm-11pm) for a solution to this SQL query I have to write. Basically, I have 2 tables and I have to select the ID from one table which has the maximum results in another. The second issue is there are 2 IDs. I can't quite explain what I mean because I'm that unsure but I can post my instructions and a link to the tables.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I've also looked at a million other posts on SO and other places but even if it seems remotely relevant, I've no idea what changes to make to suit my needs.

i.e

[SQL SELECT MAX COUNT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469372/sql-select-max-count)

So my task is as follows:-

```
Display the name and the telephone number of private owners which have more properties than anybody else.
```

[image]

The top table in the image shows the "properties for rent" table and the lower shows the "private owners".

In reference to the question, I need to use the primary key of the private owners table to count the number of properties that each private owner has available to rent and then display the details of the private owner(s) who has the most properties available - which by studying the data, is 2 private owners (CO87 and CO93).

Again, I'd appreciate any help at all with this, I've been pulling my hair out for the best part of 12 hours :/

Thanks in advance guys,

Tim.

P.s - Just for the curious, this is one of an insane amount of SQL tasks for a university assignment =)

Edit:- The owner IDs are strings, not integers.

Comment: Also, if anyone is awesome enough to provide a solution - would it be too much to ask for a generic version? Just in case anyone else comes across this tedious issue? :)

Comment: I'm going to bed now, but look into a dense_rank() function ...

Comment: Did you even try something? Instead of posting here your homework and ask to us to do it?

Comment: Of course I tried something, I don't expect you to do my homework Im asking for guidance, not a definitive solution. When you've been staring at pgAdmin's query editor since you woke up, you don't keep every attempt at hand. I'll post my attempts in the morning, for the time being I need to sleep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your process should be:

1. Get a count of properties for each owner
2. Find the owner IDs with the max # of properties
3. Find the owners with those owner ID.

Seems like this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM Owners
WHERE OwnerID IN 
  (
   SELECT OwnerID 
   FROM Properties
   GROUP BY OwnerID
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 
      (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM Properties
       GROUP BY OwnerID
       ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
       LIMIT 1)
  )
```

Comment: Just the text for the OP would be sufficient since he is trying to make us to do it homework.

Comment: See my edit - not sure if a subquery in the HAVING clause will work in postgresql, but logically that's how it would work.

Comment: So, from my understanding, I should read the query backwards? This works perfectly with a spot of editing by the way, had to replace TOP with LIMIT but it's the solution I needed. Now to try and wrap my head around it for the next task lol. Thank you very much!

Comment: Updated for postgreSQL

Comment: @Timmy yes you can read it from inside out - select the top # of properties by owner, find all owners with that # of properties.